# What is the relation between $R^{-1}$ and the set of units of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a subring of a field $F$ and $R^{-1}$ be the set $\{r^{-1}\mid 0\neq r\in R\}$.

What is the relation between $R^{-1}$ and the set of units of $R$? Are they the same?

Comment: Define $R^{-1}$ please

Comment: @user275240 not for every $r\in R$ there exists an inverse $r^{-1}$ so your $R^{-1}$ is not well defined. Secondly, add the definition in an [edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1560935/edit) to your question (not in a comment).

Comment: If $S$ is a subset of $R$ (that fulfills certain properties), then one might come across the notation $S^{-1}R$, and it is called a _localisation_. Is that related to your question?

Comment: @drhab Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: @Arthur The question is not relate to that.

Comment: @user275240: What is $0^{-1}$?

Comment: Ok, now I redefine the set $R^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, but $R^{-1}$ is still not well defined. Only the units of $R$ have inverses. Normally the set of units is denoted as $R^*$ and if $R^{-1}:=\{r^{-1}\mid r\in R^*\}$ then $R^{-1}=R^*$. This because the (unique) inverse $r^{-1}$ of $r\in R^*$ is invertible as well. Its inverse is $r$.

Comment: @drhab If I suppose that R is the subring of a field F then $R^{−1}$ is still not well define?

Comment: In that case your $R^{-1}$ is well defined. The fact that you are working in a field $F$ must be mentioned in your question, though.

Comment: Thank you.Now If I take an example $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}$ then what is $\mathbb{Z}^{-1}$?

Comment: Your definition then says that $\mathbb Z^{-1}=\{\frac1{n}\mid n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\}$

Answer (score 0):

Not the same.Take an example $R=ℤ$ and $F=ℚ$ then $ℤ^{−1}=\{\frac{1}{n}∣n∈ℤ∖\{0\}\}$ while the units of $ℤ$ are $1,-1$

Comment: Caution: if you are looking at $\mathbb Z$ as a ring on its own then its units are indeed $\{-1,1\}$. If you are looking at $\mathbb Z$ as a subring of $\mathbb Q$ then every non-zero element of $\mathbb Z$ can be classified as a unit in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Is it in this case $ℚ=\mathbb{Z^{-1}}\cup\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: No...for example $\frac{3}{4} \in \Bbb Q$, but is neither in $\Bbb Z$ nor $\Bbb Z^{-1}$.